# FIFO - Restabelecer comunicação em C++

Tags: c++, linux

Tenho um programa principal escrito em C++. Ele dispara programas filhos usando vfork() e execl(). A comunicação entre eles funciona perfeitamente utilizando FIFO (o pai escreve e o filho lê).

No programa principal a sequência para se estabelecer a comunicação é

```
if (mkfifo(CONTROLLER_file, 0666) < 0)
            perror("mkfifo");

if((aux_fd = open(CONTROLLER_file, O_RDONLY | O_NONBLOCK) )< 0)
            perror("ERRO AO ABRIR O arquivo");

if((fd = open(CONTROLLER_file, O_WRONLY)) < 0)
            perror("ERRO AO ABRIR O arquivo");
```

Faço isso para evitar o problema de bloqueio esperando outro processo abrir o arquivo no outro modo.

A escrita é feita com

```
write(fd, write_buffer, sizeof(write_buffer));
```

Do lado do filho eu faço

```
if (mkfifo(CONTROLLER_file, 0666) < 0)
            perror("mkfifo");

if((file_descriptor = open(CONTROLLER_file, O_RDONLY)) < 0)
        perror("ERRO AO ABRIR O ARQUIVO");
```

E leio com

```
fcntl(file_descriptor, F_SETFL, flags | O_NONBLOCK);
read(file_descriptor, read_buffer, sizeof(read_buffer));
```

A mensagem é enviada com sucesso.

Para testes eu mato o programa principal utilizando o kill no terminal do linux e os filhos continuam rodando. Eu chamo novamente o programa principal e ele entra na parte de restabelecer a comunicação com o mesmo procedimento apresentado acima. Tento então enviar uma mensagem para o filho, mas ele não recebe nada.

Alguem tem alguma idéia de como posso restabelecer essa comunicação?

Comment: Faça um [tour](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour) pelo stackoverflow, conheça um pouco das regras e boas práticas. Depois, edite sua pergunta e insira o código de que faz a conexão.

Comment: Editei a pergunta com código e mais detalhes @MarcoGiovanni

Comment: crie um exemplo mínimo completo e coloque aqui

Comment: Apenas para esclarecer, a idéia de usar o FIFO foi abandonada por conta de mudanças no projeto, então não atualizei o tópico. Com isso também não encontrei uma solução para o problema para compartilhar aqui.